# Cannot load such file - Ruby / Compass / Susy

Tags: ruby, node.js, gruntjs, compass, susy

When I run grunt, I keep getting the following error.  I've installed, uninstalled, reinstalled them multiple times with the same issue. On a previous PC with the same installation files it worked fine, so I'm confused as to what is causing the issue?

I have the following installed:

- Ruby 2.1.5
- Node.js 0.10.26
- compass 0.12.2
- susy 1.0.9

The error is:

```
C:\Users\jnorthrup\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\RealEstate\RealEstate.Web\assets\sass>grunt
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require': cannot load such file -- sass/script/node (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches/browser_support.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:2:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in 'each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/monkey_patches.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:9:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in 'each'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in 'require'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:20:in 'block in <top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:8:in 'fallback_load_path'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/bin/compass:19:in '<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/compass:23:in 'load'
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/compass:23:in '<main>'
Warning: ? Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: I've seen errors like this when accidentally having multiple versions of Ruby installed...you wouldn't happen to have multiple versions of Ruby installed wouldja?

Comment: Wait...do you have Sass installed? I'm pretty sure you need that too

Comment: I do have sass installed. I don't believe I have more than 1 ruby installed...how would I check that? I only see one program in the programs and features list in windows.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.  My issue was that susy was installing a later version of sass.  Once I removed that version and kept my old sass version, I was able to run grunt with out issue.

I hope this helps someone else too.